# How to use IBus with kde

Tags: kde, input-method

The KDE install on my PC includes IBus and the Japanese Anthy IME.  In the IBus preference, I have enabled the Anthy IME.  The IBus daemon is running and there is an IBus icon in the system tray, however, there does not appear to be any way of switching IMEs.

This is on PC-BSD 8.2.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you launch kde from `xinit` command , you could set the following environment variables in ~/.xinitrc ,

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

This will make all programs respect ibus. (If this don't work for you , modify `startkde4` script directly , add the 3 lines to the top of it , after `#!/bin/sh`

And also a auto-start of ibus program , `ibus-daemon -xd` , set this in `systemsettings` , there's something named "Startup" , can't remember the exact name

Comment: I have all of that; yet in Firefox <kbd>Compose " o</kbd> correctly yields `ö`, but in Konsole it yields `̈́o` — see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/489134/15654).

Answer (score 2):

First, run `ps -ef | grep ibus` to check that the daemon is running with the correct option. There should be a process like `ibus-daemon --xim`.

Second, beware of the program you use to test iBus. For example, Kate (the KDE text editor) doesn't work with iBus (or at least not by default, you'll have to look more if you want that). I believe other KDE apps are like Kate as well, though I'm not sure. I use Chromium or Firefox to test iBus (click on the address bar and perform the key combination).

Third, (you may have already discovered that) iBus only functions properly once you have logged out and logged back in.

Update: a little searching revealed that there is [ibus-qt](http://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/Install#ibus-qt) for KDE applications.

Comment: Hi,

Even if Firefox, ctrl-space (the configured shortcut) seems to do nothing.  The ibus icon in the systray brings up the message "No input window" when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD-13.0 running KDE Plasma 5.23.4, I have to add below lines in Autostart to get ibus working. **Autostart** - you can find in KDE Menu.

```
/usr/local/bin/ibus-daemon  -drxR
```